# Monitoring Azure AD object limit

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a simple way for a customer to monitor and be notified when getting close to the Azure AD object limit? This customer has extended to 1m objects already and is planning to extend further, but would like to be able to know before the threshold is reached.

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the answer that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.(To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no.

The best you can do on your own is to list and count users, groups, service principals, applications, contacts and policies, to get a sense of overall growth rate. Keep in mind that this wouldn't take into account recently-deleted objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no such way to monitor the Azure AD object limit. We can only know the  approximate count which will be less than actual count.